# Schmitt trigger issues... lumpy outputs and wrong switching voltages

Tags: simulation, troubleshooting, schmitt-trigger

I'm trying to implement the Schmitt trigger found in "CMOS" by J. Baker. Here's what the circuit should look like:

[image]

And this is how the transistors should be dimensioned to achieve switching voltages of 0.7V and 0.4V:

[image]

And here's what the output should look like:

[image]

This is what my circuit and simulation results look like:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, my Schmitt trigger doesn't switch at the correct voltages and the output is all lumpy.

In terms of troubleshooting, I have double-checked the connections and transistor dimensions. Also, I played around with the voltage source Vdc to see if I needed a larger voltage. Adjusting the voltage higher than 1Vdc breaks the circuit entirely.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this SCHMIDTT much more controllable

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftEtNf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how do I dimension the transistors? with the same equations in my original post?